# How do I properly use if/then for a bolean value in order to make an object visible?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to display an endless access form. For each data set there is a yes/no value (PA). If yes, then a hidden object should be displayed. It seems very straight forward, but it doesn't work.

I have tried by changing the value of PA to 1, 0, -1. Either nothing happens, or the object will be displayed for all data sets.

The object is defined as hidden in the form.

---

```
Private sub form_current()

If PA.value = true Then
 me.object.visible = True
End if

End Sub
```

---

I would be very happy for some advice. /LP

Answer (score 2):

Handle the control's `Change` event, and then you can assign to its value:

```
Private Sub PA_Change()
    Me.object.Visible = PA.Value ' TODO: give 'object' an actual name
End Sub
```

Find `PA` in the top-left codepane dropdown, then select the `Change` event in the top-right code pane dropdown if it's not automatically selected - the VBE will generate the event handler procedure for you.

Answer (score 1):

As the object is unbound, you can't do this. When unbound, it will either be visible or not - for all records.

One workaround is to move the control to a tiny subform having a master/child relation to the main form.

Comment: This is probably more accurate - my answer assumes Access forms work similarly to MSForms, which may not be true (I'm not very familiar with Access, but I know for a fact Access form modules have more in common with Excel worksheet modules than a MSForms UserForm).

Comment: A userform is very different from an Access form.

Comment: Exactly - they're *document modules* owned by Access, just like Worksheet modules in Excel; a UserForm is owned by the VBProject, not its host document.